# Do I get a performance bonus if I try to use arm math assembler commands instead of c

Tags: android, c, assembly, arm

I have cycle in my application in which executed mathematical multiply and addition calculations.

I know some facts:

- android devices supports armv6 and up processors
- armv6 not supported NEON commands

Does i increase performance of application on armv6 including, and up, if instead of c math commands i will start using assembler math commands?

**UPDATE**

i need to execute cycle with math operation faster, is right way to use assembler instead of c.

**UPDATE**

i have this calculation:

```
Ry0 = (b0a0 * buffer[index] + b1a0 * Rx1 + b2a0 * Rx2 - a1a0 * Ry1
                    - a2a0 * Ry2);
```

it is  biquad transfer function.

Can i force execute this calculation faster with asm?

**UPDATE**

- buffer size is 192000
- variables is float type

Comment: How can someone else measure your application's performance? Try doing it both ways then compare your results.

Comment: No, the compiler will figure that out, easily. Humans used to outperform compilers in the 1980's, but that's a long time ago.

Comment: This is 21st century, compilers are a lot more smarter than it was back in the dark ages, so *pro-tip* do not try outwit the compiler and thinking you're cleverer than these software tools... just saying :)

Comment: @BoPersson: I totally disagree. I work with extremely optimized code and write lots of ARM assembly. I beat GCC, LLVM and RVCT when it comes to writing optimized assembly on a regular basis. It requires quite a bit of practice and takes a LOT of time, but saying that humans do not outperform compilers is just incorrect.

Comment: Compilers can never outperform humans with infinite run-time.  Unfortunately, no human has infinite run time.  There are many nuances that the C standards zealots like to point out.  If the algorithm doesn't need them, then it is always possible to outperform a compiler.  The best of both worlds is to use *inline assembler*.  ARM has various *multiply-accumulate* instructions.  If the compiler is not generating these, *inline assembler* can easily handle this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compilers are pretty good at their job, so unless you KNOW what your compiler is producing, and know that you can do better, probably not.

Without knowing exactly what your code does, it would be impossible to give a better answer.

Edit: to summarize this discussion:
The FIRST step in improving performance is not to start writing assembler. The first step is to find the most efficient algorithm. Once that has been done you can look at assembler coding.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more context: what size is buffer, what type are the different variables? 
What code does the compiler produce? Have you looked at it, and spotted places where you can improve?

Comment: I'm newby in asm i don't looked at compiler's code, how do that

Comment: @testCoder - check the documentation for your compiler, it should have a command line switch to output assembler. Also, you can set it up so that you have 1 function per source file, compile them to objects (.o or .obj) and then decompile this to the asm level - note that these are advanced operations!

Comment: Please note, this is not one of the common “I want my code to go faster” questions we see frequently on StackOverflow. The IIR is a signal processing function, and it is something that occurs in situations where performance is very desirable and for which extra effort is suitable. This is one of the situations that justifies not trusting the compiler.

Comment: Yes, but improving it will still depend on doing a better job than the compiler (or finding someone else that can do this). I appologise for not being a DSP expert, but like your answer says, the FIRST step is not to start writing assembler. The first step is to find the most efficient algorithm. Once that has been done you can look at assembler coding.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You should add your last comment to your answer. Assembly can definitely help, but as you said, it is the last step in a long chain of optimizations.

Answer (score 8):

Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) functions are difficult to implement with high performance because each output element depends closely on the immediately preceding output element. This compels a latency from output to output. This dependency chain defeats common high-performance techniques (such as SIMD, strip mining, and superscalar execution).

Working in assembly initially is not a good approach to this. At some point, working in assembly may help. However, you have a fundamental issue to resolve: You cannot produce a new output until you have completed the previous output, multiplied it by a coefficient, and added the results of additional arithmetic. Therefore, the best you can do with this formulation is to produce one output as frequently as the processor can do a multiply and an add from start to finish, even supposing the other work can be done in parallel.

It is mathematically possible to rewrite the IIR so that the output depends on other outputs and inputs further in the past, instead of the immediately previous output. This uses more arithmetic but provides a possibility of doing more of the arithmetic in parallel, thus obtaining higher throughput.

On an iPhone or other iOS device, you could simply call vDSP_deq22 in the Accelerate framework. Accelerate is an Apple library, so it is not available on Android. However, perhaps somebody has implemented something similar.

One approach is to measure how many processor cycles each output is taking (calculate many, divide time by number of outputs, multiply by processor speed) to the latency, in cycles, of a multiplication from an addition (from the documentation for the processor model you are using).  If the time taken is the same as the latency, then it is impossible to perform this arithmetic any more quickly on that processor, and you must either accept it or find an alternate solution with different math.

Comment: I noticed Ne10 has some iir implementation, so leaving that as a reference to future readers:
https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/tree/master/modules/dsp.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to gain some extra speed by taking a look at what your compiler does, but this should be the last thing you do. First take a good look at your algorithm and variable types.

Since your target is ARMv6, the first thing I would do is to switch from floating-point to fixed-point arithmetic. ARMv6 usually has no or very slow hardware floating point support. ARMv7 is usually better, but for ARM, fixed-point arithmetic is usually a lot faster than floating-point implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports ARMv5TE and ARMv7-A. Read NDK docs about supported CPU ARCHs & ABIs available at `$NDK/docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html`.

ARMv5TE is default and doesn't give you any hardware floating point support, you can see [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) page more about this. You should add ARMv7-A support to your application to get best support from hardware.

ARMv6 is somewhere in between and if you want to target these devices you must do some `Android.mk` trickery.

Nowadays if you are coding a modern app you'll be probably targeting newer devices with ARMv7-A processor type having VFPv3 and NEON. If you just want to *support* ARMv6, you should use ARMv5TE to cover those. If you want to take advantage of a little bit extra provided by ARMv6 then you'll loose ARMv5TE support completely.

I compiled your simple line of code with NDK r8c, and it can produce me a binary like below. Best ARM VFP allows for your statement is `multiply and accumulate` instruction which is `fmac` and compiler can emit these easly.

```
00000000 <f>:
   0:   ee607aa2    fmuls   s15, s1, s5
   4:   ed9f7a05    flds    s14, [pc, #20]
   8:   ee407a07    fmacs   s15, s0, s14
   c:   ee417a03    fmacs   s15, s2, s6
  10:   ee417ae3    fnmacs  s15, s3, s7
  14:   eeb00a67    fcpys   s0, s15
  18:   ee020a44    fnmacs  s0, s4, s8
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

It might be better to divide your statement into a few chunks to get dual issuing possible but you can do this in C.

You can't create miracles by just using assembly however compiler can also create a huge crap. GCC and ARM is not as good as GCC and Intel. Especially in vectorization, NEON usage. It is always good to check what compiler produces if you need to have high performing routines.

Comment: NEON is of little help with IIRs, because the dependence of each output on the immediately preceding output forces serialization.